# making a jsp custom tag run each time i select an option from a select option

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a select tag in my JSP page. After selecting the value from the dropdown menu I want my JSTL custom tag run. I want to do it using jQuery so that I don't have to reload my whole page.
My custom tag is working fine. The problem is that I want to select the table from the database based on the value I select from that dropdown menu and then run that custom tag to display the value i got from the table.

Comment: Hope you might be creating the `custom-tag` statically to test. All the `jsp` tags will be compiled and rendered into `HTML` during the page load. If you create it dynamically using javascript (`jQuery`), it won't render the custom-tag  until it's get reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I am just loading the div that contains my custom tag. It works fine with that.